# Javascripts for customization in microstrategy

Tags: javascript, microstrategy

I am working on a MicroStrategy project in which I have a grid that contains data in the following the format:

```
ID   |   Name
1    |   Abc
2    |   Def
3    |   Ghi
```

and I want to use column ID as selector within the grid, so that when the users click the ID, the value of ID should be passed to an HTML container in the same document (HTML container contains the link to another report which has a value prompt that is answered by this ID).

My boss has told me that I will need a JavaScript to do that.

So any help will be appreciated to do so with or without JavaScript.
Also if anyone knows where can I learn to write JavaScript for MicroStrategy, that will be appreciated as well!

Thank You!

Comment: Lol. Thanks! Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to above problem without using JavaScripts.
We just have to answer the value prompts by adding
**&valuePromptAnswers={[AttributeName]@ID}**
at the end of URL. And this should work fine.